# iOS #include "mupdf/fitz.h" not found issue

Tags: ios, pdf, cocoapods, mupdf

I am integrating muPDF library in my projects.I already update cocopods and install pods again. Its showing an issue.

```
#include "mupdf/fitz.h" library not found.
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOjm6.png]

Any possible solution for this issue ?

Comment: It's best if you also include the detail from the build log on what it was trying to include etc (ie. right click the error and click 'Reveal in log' and then copy the relevant line as paste into question as an edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to build https://github.com/jogu/MuPDF-example  ?

I just cloned that, and ran:

```
gem install cocoapods
pod install
```

then opened `MuPDF-example.xcworkspace` and hit "Run".

Everything worked, it displayed hello-world.pdf.

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and CocoaPods 1.0.1, and the very latest code on the master of that git repo for the example (I'm the owner of that repo btw :) ). If exactly the same thing is falling for you, try deleting everything and starting again. Did you make any changes to the example project?

Comment: Thanks. But Can i run it without cocoa ? Do you have any fresh source link ? @JosephH

Comment: Yes, you can run it without cocoapods, but I would suggest that if you're struggling to sort out an include path error then you really should use the cocoapod which will sort out the include paths for you. What's wrong with using the cocoa pod? What's wrong with the source link I gave you?

Comment: Can you provide me a sample project with every resource include in the projects. Again and again  get error. it may take your 10minutes. Please.

Comment: @jamshed If you use cocoa pods, it doesn't work for you? Or you want a sample that doesn't use cocoapods?

Comment: Seriously, just use CocoaPods. This is exactly the problem it's there to solve. There's no reason not to use it.

Comment: i have download your project from git. Installed cocoapods after your suggestion. in app delegate, you import #import "mupdf/MuDocRef.h" but there is no #import "mupdf/MuDocRef.h" file with the  project. So not found error.
Whats wrong ?

Comment: @jamshed It sounds like you haven't run "pod install", or that it has failed somehow. After running pod install, I have several mupdf/MuDocRef.h files. You should too. Did it print out any errors when you ran "pod install"?

Comment: @JosephH Could you update your CocoaPods to new version of MuPDF library?